# Failed to load viewstate. DropDownList in GridView

Tags: asp.net

I get this error when adding a `DropDownList` to the `EditItemTemplate`:

```
Failed to load viewstate. 
The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match  
the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request. 
For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back.
```

I am doing the Binding on code behind in the RowDataBound event. How do I properly add this control here?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the Data to gridview only when its not a post back, as

```
....
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
       If(!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
             ......
             gridview.DataBind();
             .....
       }
...
}
```

Comment: With `EnableViewState = True` on the `GridView` I get the same error, if I set that to `False` the `GridView` disappears when I click the `Edit` button??? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Data comes from a `WCF WebService` if that makes a diff!